# Why is a snapshot of a general wave at a particular time $t_0$ appears to be the mirrored image of the waveform at $x_0$?

Tags: waves

In my physics lecture notes, there is this figure:

[image]

The notes are talking about general waves.

What is the intuitive interpretation of this symmetry? (Ie why the two figures look the same with a mirroring?)

I would also welcome a non-intuitive proof of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi(x,t) = f(x-vt)$ which is a common representation for a general wave moving to the right.

Then for $t_0 = 0$ we get $\psi(x,0) = f(x)$ and for $x_0 = 0$ we get $\psi(0,t) = f(-vt)$. Then letting $v=1$, without losing generality, we that $\psi(0,t) = f(-t)$.  So they are mirror images of each other. (The propagation velocity, $v$, acts as a scale factor.)

Another way of thinking about is is to compare $f(x-t)$ with $f(-t+x)$ while in each case considering the second variable to be a parameter and the first to be the function's controlling variable. Both equations describe a wave moving to the right with a wave shape $f$ but one wave shape is the mirror image of the other when they are plotted wrt the controlling variable.